# I set this server commando in php?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, server

I need to get this command:

```
awk '{w=NF?$NF:w} END{print w}' file.log
```

in PHP

```
$land = system(" awk '{w=NF $NF:w} END{print w}' file.log");
```

I tried like this but PHP thinks that `$NF` is a variable...
so I need *the last field of a log file!*

Comment: and also i need this for the whole file - so in the file are many logs.. but the server just gives me the last string of the first log in the file - i think i need to do this with -g ( for global ) but i dont know where do i need to set the -g

Comment: if the comment is addition to your question, please edit your question and delete the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the $NF "variable" like this

```
$land = system(" awk '{w=NF \$NF:w} END{print w}' file.log");
```